# Отредактировать таблицу mysql через Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

На компьютере с адресом 192.168.10.10 установлен сервер MySQL
На другом компьютере с адресом 192.68.10.12 установлен Python с программой, которая по идее должна делать в таблицу базы данных записи. MySQLConnector установлен, к базе данных получается подключиться, но добавить записи в существующую таблицу - нет, выдает ошибку MySQL Connection is not available и после этого к базе данных не подключиться.

Используемый код:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
    
try:
    with connect(
        host="192.168.10.10",
        user="root",
        password="passwd1",
        database="ANHOR",
    ) as connection:
       insert_results_query = """
INSERT INTO results (Name, Points)
VALUES
("Stable34", 5)
    """
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(insert_results_query)
        connection.close()
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

В чем причина и как решить проблему?

Comment: А как вы узнали, что "к базе данных получается подключиться" ?

Comment: @strawdog, буквально за пару минут до возникновения ошибки в коде вместо записи был запрос списка таблиц базы данных, все выводилось